# I wish to play audio from an array that contains audio urls , but it is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

```
const [handleSet, setHandleSet] = useState(true)
  const audioRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement | null>(null)

  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)

  const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.currentTarget.blur()
    setHandleSet(!handleSet)
    playAudio()
  }

  const playAudio = useCallback(() => {
    if (audioRef.current) {
      if (handleSet) {
        audioRef.current.play()
      } else {
        audioRef.current.pause()
      }
    }
  }, [handleSet])

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleEnded = () => {
      setIndex(index + 1)
      playAudio()
    }

    const newAudioRef = audioRef.current

    newAudioRef?.addEventListener('ended', handleEnded)

    return () => {
      newAudioRef?.removeEventListener('ended', handleEnded)
    }
  }, [index, playAudio]) /////

/////
  <div>
            <Button onClick={handleClick}>{handleSet ? 'Play All' : 'Pause All'}</Button>
            <StyledAudio ref={audioRef} src={trendingTopics[index]?.audio_EN}>
              <track kind="captions" />
            </StyledAudio>
          </div>
```

I have tried a couple of things ,but they do not seem to work, I use Ref to store the src of audio files it is in and array the functionality seems to work when I manually trigger the button that is the index is updated but the autoplay functionality does not work

Comment: The autoplay functionality might not be working due to browser policies that prevent the autoplay of media with sound. To overcome this, you can try adding the muted attribute to your audio element.